# content aware noun definition

Tags: formatting

I would like to define some terminology in my document, something similar to
`\def\name{noun}` but I would like to make `\name` modify the value "noun" depending on the context it is used in. For instance, if it is the first word, I would like the uppercase initial. I would also like to be able to make choices depending on what text immediately precedes or follows the command. Would that be possible somehow? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is probably better to store noun under then name »name« and then make various macros that can retrieve »noun« via »name«, then those macros can then apply transformations to »noun«. I don't think you can have latex automatically know when you are at the start of a new sentence.

Comment: @daleif checking for the begin of a sentence is possible, but would have many potential false-positives or false-negatives. All in all I totally agree with you, it would be better to define and use the different usecases by hand.

Comment: @Skillmon exactly, I'm guessing that's why cleveref has cref and Cref

Comment: Could you provide some more context? Perhaps some explicit examples of what you want and use cases for `\name`?

Comment: @Werner For now mainly the initial uppercase for the beginning of sentence and some  transformation that depend on the article - this does not work in english but to make an example, I could transform a little "noun" depending on whether `\name` is used after "the" as opposed to "an".

Comment: @MichelePicchione: TeX gobbles letters and words without really caring what they mean/stand for. So, to change the meaning of something *after* having read in some arbitrary `the` or `an` would be difficult, unless you explicitly tell TeX to do something different. For example, via `\article{the} \name{noun}`, or `\name{the noun}`, say. If this seems too cumbersome, you may have to consider parsing the input stream via something like LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Werner thanks I will consider that.